# Finding multi dimensional, analytical relationship (curve fitting) for experimental data

Tags: least-squares, data-analysis

I have an unknown relationship like

$$
y = f(M, R, \sigma, P)
$$

I would like to find an analytical relationship that fits observed data the best.

As an example, if I keep $\sigma=0.3$ and $P=7$ constant, I get the following curves from the experiment:

[image]

I can fit each of these curves into equations of the form

$$
y = a (M + b)^n
$$

where $a$, $b$, $n$ are fitting parameters which I find via Least Squares.

However, how do I incorporate the relationship for $R$?

If I repeat the experiment but pick another $\sigma$ and $P$, the curves have the same shape (i.e., can  be described again by $y = a (M + b)^n$) but $a$, $b$, $n$ are all different. How can I incorporate $\sigma$ and $P$ to find the generic $f$ of a form $y = a (M + b)^n$?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. You know the science behind your experiment, so you can guess an analytic form. It looks like it's not the case for your problem.
2. You need to fit for many $R, \sigma, P$ parameters the curve and plot $a, b, n$ as a function of $R, \sigma, P$